# How to establish a symbol, a character as a condition for loop

Tags: c, loops

I'm trying to put a loop on my code(a simple calculator), where it restarts if you try to divide some number per 0. I'm here for hours but can't manage to see the problem. I'm a beginner by the way.

Tried using do while, using while and using if, every time the program simple ignores my condition. Now it is looping every time even without the conditions that I established being fulfilled.

How do I establish "N2=0 and operation being '/'" as a condition?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    float N1, N2, resultado;
    char operacao;

    printf("Ola usuario! \n");
    printf("Para comecar, por favor digite o primeiro numero: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &N1);
    printf("Digite o segundo numero: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &N2);

    printf("\n Qual operacao aritmetica deseja realizar hoje? \n");
    printf("Escolha um dos 4 simbolos'+,-,* ou /': ");
    scanf_s(" %c", &operacao);
    printf("\n");

    while ((N2 = 0) || (operacao == '/')); {
        printf("Operacao nao suportada! \n");
        printf("Digite novamente o segundo numero: \n");
        scanf_s("%f", &N2);
        printf("Escolha um dos 4 simbolos'+,-,* ou /': ");
        scanf_s(" %c ", &operacao);
    }

    switch (operacao)
    {
    case '+':
        resultado = N1 + N2;
        break;
    case '-':
        resultado = N1 - N2;
        break;
    case '*':
        resultado = N1 * N2;
        break;
    case '/':
        resultado = N1 / N2;
        break;

    }

    printf("\n O resultado da operacao escolhida e: %.1f", resultado);
    printf("\n\n");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `N2=0` should probably be `N2==0.` N2=0 always is false.

Comment: oh thanks, changed that but now when the conditions are fulfilled the program just stops, the '_' keeps blinking on the prompt. And when the conditions are Not fulfilled the loop happens, what in the world is happening?

Comment: You are using `scanf_s` with `%c` specifier incorrectly. *"Unlike `scanf` ... `scanf_s` ... requires the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string control sets that are enclosed in []. **The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter** immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable."* Please pay attention to compiler warnings.

Comment: There's also a stray `;` at the end of your `while` loop.

Comment: hmm kind of didn't understand where are you coming from. Should i use scanf? Bc when i try the visual studio says that i should use scanf_s instead. And in reality the calculator is functional, i'm just not managing to put the loop

Comment: That's because MS is trying to impose its own non-standard functions.

Comment: Oh my good that `;` was the whole problem! Thanks @dbush and all of you.

Comment: To put them in their place, *before* any `#include` headers add `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` and `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE` and `#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE`

Comment: Oh i see @weather Vane. My teacher said that we should use scanf but the new versions of Visual Studio didn't allow it, maybe thats the reason why he started to use CodeBlock instead, to teach us the standard function.

Comment: They do: they just emit warnings, but those warnings obcsure relevent ones.

Comment: I will start to use these definers now, many thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Change the while loop as follows

```
 while (N2 == 0 && operacao == '/') {
    printf("Operacao nao suportada! \n");
    printf("Digite novamente o segundo numero: \n");
    scanf("%f", &N2);
    printf("Escolha um dos 4 simbolos'+,-,* ou /': ");
    scanf("%c", &operacao);
}
```

Removed the stray ; at the end of 
      while (N2 == 0 && operacao == '/')
That caused an infinite loop preventing it to proceed to the actual body we wanted to execute.
Changed the while loop condition as we want it to execute only if N2 is zero 'AND' operacao is '/' not in any other case.

Comment: This answer would be much better if you explained what you changed & why.

Comment: `" %c "` is a poor choice.  Consider `" %c"` to allow `scanf()` to promptly return.